# Corsair RGB hub and fans

Tags: cpu-cooler, water-cooling, corsair

Does the Corsair RGB hub literally just control the lighting of Corsair water coolers or does it also have something to do with the management of fans and water cooler pumps?

On my new PC the cooler radiator fans don't spin or light up and the pump unit has red flashing lights. The CPU overheats and shuts itself down. I've checked all the other connectors in the PC are secure, have I overlooked the connectors on the RGB hub as a cause of the pump not working?

It's currently packed up to to back to the shop to be looked at, I don't want to send it back if it's just something simple that I've overlooked.